# C# how to trigger MouseMove or MouseEnter events if MouseButton is down when entering a control?

Tags: c#, eventtrigger

I need to trigger MouseMove or MouseEnter event, while Mouse LeftButton is down. Unfortunately while the Mouse LeftButton is down, those events are not triggered.

I already tried the solution in this thread :
[C# triggering MouseEnter even even if mouse button is held down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457814/c-sharp-triggering-mouseenter-even-even-if-mouse-button-is-held-down)

But it doesnt work because it's working on the Form only and not the controls.
The idea is simple, let's say I have 10 labels next to each others.
After I MouseDown on one label --> its background color change to red, and then I keep the MouseLeftButton down and keep moving the mouse to other labels, I would like those labels backcolor to also change to red, without having releasing the mouse at any point.

I tried to use a boolean variable to store the state of the mouse button, at MouseDown event --> MouseDown = true;
Then use that boolean at MouseEnter, or MouseMove, but those events are simply not triggered.
Thanks all.

Comment: _But it doesnt work because it's working on the Form only and not the controls._ Well it will if you write the necessary code, ie if you test for controls you want to catch entering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must be in the MouseDown event use `Label.Capture = false;` that this event to allow other events to run .

I put the complete code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   bool Ispressed = false; 
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      for(int i=1; i<=10;i++)
      {
          Label lbl = new Label();
          lbl.Name = "lbl" + i;
          lbl.Text = "Label " + i;
          lbl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(150, i * 40);
          lbl.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(Lbl_MouseDown);
          lbl.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(Lbl_MouseUp);
          lbl.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(Lbl_MouseMove);
          lbl.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(Lbl_MouseLeave);
          this.Controls.Add(lbl);
      }
   }
   private void Lbl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
      if (Ispressed)
      {
          Label lbl = sender as Label;
          lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;
      }
   }

   private void Lbl_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Label lbl = sender as Label;
      lbl.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
   }       
   private void Lbl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
      Label lbl = sender as Label;
      lbl.BackColor = Color.Red;

      lbl.Capture = false;
      Ispressed = true;
   }
   private void Lbl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       Ispressed = false;
       foreach(Control ctr in this.Controls)
       {
          if(ctr is Label)
          {
             ctr.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
          }
       }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Look good but I can't get it to work.

Comment: ok, it does; just not what I thought was needed: when moving control1 over control2 it doesn't help to turn off Capture on control1. Only observing the position helps. But re-reading the question, I think he may not need that..